# how to make golang grpc clients follow redirects

Tags: go, grpc, tls1.2

I have a server that redirects to server:443 when connecting to server:80. I have a grpc client that is connecting to server:80 with

```
clientConn, err = grpc.Dial("server:80", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(credentials.NewTLS(config)))
```

Its throwing a "tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake" error. Is there a way to make the client follow the redirects?

Answer (score 1):

gRPC client does not handle 302 redirects. See this https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/5330 - this is for Java but also applies to Golang.